# Merging CSV entries by date and counting the entries per date

Tags: python, pandas, count, pandas-groupby

I have a CSV file that I'm using Pandas DataFrame to manipulate. The data that I have is Tweet data, and what I'm trying to do is merge the cells according to the date but also add an extra column that displays the count for how many Tweets there were in a particular day. For example:

*Example Original DataFrame:*

```
date        mentions    photos    replies    retweets    likes    polarity
2011-04-01     0          1         10          5          10        0.1
2011-04-01     1          1          5          3          20       -0.3
2011-04-02     2          0         15          2           5        0.5
2011-04-02     3          0          0          4         100       -0.5
2011-04-02     0          1          2          1          50        0.9
2011-04-03     1          1          1          2           2        0.2
```

*Expected Output DataFrame:*

```
date      mentions    photos    replies    retweets    likes    polarity  counts
2011-04-01     1          2         15          8        30       -0.2       2
2011-04-02     5          1         17          7       155        0.9       3   
2011-04-03     1          1          1          2         2        0.2       1
```

Normally I'd use `pd.DataFrame().groupby(['date']).sum()` and it'll merge the cells according to date and also sum up the other column values, but now I would like to add an extra column on the right counting the number of Tweets. I hope I'm being clear enough, but if not please let me know.

Is there a built-in library functionality that takes care of this, or would I have to code it manually?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simpliest is add new column created by [`DataFrame.assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) and [`Series.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html):

```
df = df.groupby('date').sum().assign(counts=df['date'].value_counts())
print (df)
            mentions  photos  replies  retweets  likes  polarity  counts
date                                                                    
2011-04-01         1       2       15         8     30      -0.2       2
2011-04-02         5       1       17         7    155       0.9       3
2011-04-03         1       1        1         2      2       0.2       1
```

General solution - create dictionary for aggregate with `dict.fromkeys` by all columns without `date` - it is possible use for aggregate `size`,but last is necessary `rename` it:

```
d = dict.fromkeys(df.columns.difference(['date']), 'sum')
d['date'] = 'size'
df = df.groupby('date').agg(d).rename(columns={'date':'counts'})
print (df)
            likes  mentions  photos  polarity  replies  retweets  counts
date                                                                    
2011-04-01     30         1       2      -0.2       15         8       2
2011-04-02    155         5       1       0.9       17         7       3
2011-04-03      2         1       1       0.2        1         2       1
```

**Detail**:

```
print (d)
{'likes': 'sum', 'mentions': 'sum', 'photos': 'sum', 'polarity': 'sum', 
 'replies': 'sum', 'retweets': 'sum', 'date': 'size'}
```